# margin within a subset plot

Tags: r, graphics, plot, margin

When we select the entire data range, we get a plot with a slight margin inside the plot region so that the plot doesn't touch the bounding box. However when we subset a plot, the margin is gone. Is there a way to add this margin? In the lower figure, I would like the line to go all the way to 5, but no further. I went through the `?par` list and can't come up with something usable.

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, type = "l")
plot(1:10, 1:10, type = "l", xlim = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a very roundabout way to do it, but here is one possibility with the example you've provided:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, type = "n", xlim = c(1, 5))
usr = par("usr")
clip(usr[1], 5, usr[3], usr[4])
lines(1:10, 1:10, type = "l", xlim = c(1, 5))
```

Comment: Much better than my more "internal" method.

Answer (score 2):

The concern you are expressing is a dislike for how `plot.default` handles the limiting of the objects passed to xy.coords. You would rather that they get restricted or subsetted. You can do that by defining a new plot function with these added features:

```
 # need a helper function for this
 tweak <- function(x) c(range(x)[1], range(x)[2]+.00001)
 # Replace xy <- xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log)
 xy <- xy.coords(x[findInterval(x, tweak(xlim))==1], 
                 y[findInterval(x, tweak(xlim))==1], 
                 xlabel, ylabel, log)
```

If your intent were to preserve the ylimits, you would need to specify those either in your call or in the code. My preference would be to do it in the call, but I am illustrating it as done automatically.

```
plotsub <- function(x,y = NULL, type = "p", xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, 
    log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
    ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, panel.first = NULL, 
    panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, ...) 
{   ylim=range(y);  tweak <- function(x) c(range(x)[1], range(x)[2]+.00001)
    localAxis <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) Axis(...)
    localBox <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) box(...)
    localWindow <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) plot.window(...)
    localTitle <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) title(...)
    xlabel <- if (!missing(x)) 
        deparse(substitute(x))
    ylabel <- if (!missing(y)) 
        deparse(substitute(y))
    xy <- xy.coords(x[findInterval(x, tweak(xlim))==1], y[findInterval(x,tweak(xlim))==1], xlabel, ylabel, log)
    xlab <- if (is.null(xlab)) 
        xy$xlab
    else xlab
    ylab <- if (is.null(ylab)) 
        xy$ylab
    else ylab
    xlim <- if (is.null(xlim)) 
        range(xy$x[is.finite(xy$x)])
    else xlim
    ylim <- if (is.null(ylim)) 
        range(xy$y[is.finite(xy$y)])
    else ylim
    dev.hold()
    on.exit(dev.flush())
    plot.new()
    localWindow(xlim, ylim, log, asp, ...)
    panel.first
    plot.xy(xy, type, ...)
    panel.last
    if (axes) {
        localAxis(if (is.null(y)) 
            xy$x
        else x, side = 1, ...)
        localAxis(if (is.null(y)) 
            x
        else y, side = 2, ...)
    }
    if (frame.plot) 
        localBox(...)
    if (ann) 
        localTitle(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
            ...)
    invisible()
}
```

The call:

```
plotsub(1:10, 1:10, type = "l", xlim = c(1, 5), ylim=c(1,10) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not subsetting the data but setting limits to the plot. A priori subsetting gives you the behaviour that you want.

```
plot(1:5, 1:5, type = "l")
```

Comment: I mention that we're subsetting a plot (second sentence). Things get more complicated when we're trying to plot a `gam` object where fitted values and SE band changes with different number of units selected. I wish I had prepared a gam example to make this clear. Would you be interested in modifying your answer if I add this to my question?